# Split csv file where the separator also appears in the text

Tags: c#, split

I have to split the following line from an csv file

1111,"Company Name","Street 70","Building Nr.1, 1st Floor, Room 34",City,2213

Currently i am using the following code. but it only works if the separator does not appear in the text

```
var values = line.Split(',');
```

The upper string is resolved in this way

```
values[0] 1111 
values[1] "Company Name" 
values[2] "Street 70" 
values[3] "Building Nr.1
values[4] 1st Floor
values[5] Room 34"
values[6] City
values[7] 2213
```

but I would have to resolve it that way

```
values[0] 1111 
values[1] "Company Name" 
values[2] "Street 70" 
values[3] "Building Nr.1, 1st Floor, Room 34"
values[4] City
values[5] 2213
```

Has someone an idea how to parameterize the split so that it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone cares. Found the following solution for me.

```
var text = "";
var isCharInValue = false;
foreach (var currentChar in line)
{
    if (currentChar == '"')
    {
        if (isCharInValue == false)
        {
            isCharInValue = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isCharInValue = false;
        }
    }
    if (isCharInValue == true && currentChar == ',')
    {
        text = text + ";;;;;;;;";
    }
    else
    {
        text = text + currentChar;
    }
}



var values = text.Split(',');

int xx1 = values.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < xx1; i++)
{
    values[i] = values[i].Replace(";;;;;;;;", ",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a library to do the parsing of the CSV for you. This will deal with ignoring delimiters in the values (if they are quoted).

I've used CsvHelper before - it's really good.

https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

If you want to roll your own, then you can look at the code for CsvHelper, although it gets quite complicated:

https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvParser.cs

Answer (score -1):

If you need a simple solution, you can use a function like this.
String splitting ignores split char inside values with a double-quote.

We go through the characters of the string and divide them into elements when finding the separator character.
If we encounter a double quotation mark character, then in the following characters we ignore the separator, after finding the closing double quotation marks, we continue to divide the string.

```
static List<string> CustomStringSplit(string inputString, char splitChar)
{
    if (splitChar == '"')
        throw new Exception("Wrong split char");

    var result = new List<string>();
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var isCharInValue = false;
    foreach (var currentChar in inputString)
    {
        if (currentChar == splitChar && !isCharInValue)
        {
            result.Add(stringBuilder.ToString());
            stringBuilder.Clear();
        }
        else if (currentChar == '"')
        {
            isCharInValue = !isCharInValue;
        }
        else
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(currentChar);
        }
    }
    result.Add(stringBuilder.ToString());

    return result;
}
```

For example string (added empty elements at the beginning and end):

```
var inputString = "\"\",1111,\"Company Name\",\"Street 70\",\"Building Nr.1, 1st Floor, Room 34\",City,2213,";
```

We get elements:

```
0 - ""
1 - "1111"
2 - "Company Name" 
3 - "Street 70" 
4 - "Building Nr.1, 1st Floor, Room 34"
5 - "City"
6 - "2213"
7 - ""
```